# Impossible set correct view title for mobile view

Tags: css

We have set the appearance of products for the desktop view and for larger phones.
But we can not set it properly for smaller phones in any way.

Below the photo and code

```
/* Products list - view list */
.products-list .item .item-inner .box-info-list {
margin-left: 150px;
padding: 2px;
}
.products-list .item .item-inner {
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.products-list .item .item-inner:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 2px #ccc;
}

.products-list .item .item-inner .box-image-list {
width: 140px;
border: 0px solid #ddd;
}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.products-list .item .item-inner .box-info-list .product-name {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 90.33%;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.products-list .item .item-inner .box-image-list {
width: 30%;
border: 0px solid #ddd;
}
.products-list .item .item-inner .box-info-list {
margin-left: 140px;
padding: 2px;
}
}
```

correct:
[image]

correct:
[image]

correct:
[image]

issue screen:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Sylvester, can you also provide the html?

Comment: Hi @Arvie You can check here: https://zabezcen.pl/pl/elektronika.html

Comment: @Sylvester don't link to a outside source provide the html in the question. We are not going to dig trough browser rendered code. Also if your website changes the question wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer to use `flexbox` with `CSS3` for responsive web design. You could try something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .products-list .item .item-inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .products-list .item .item-inner .box-image-list {
    flex-basis: 30%;
  }

  .products-list .item .item-inner .box-info-list {
    flex-basis: 65%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Antonis,  after use your code looks better, but still not display correct. Can you please check again? Thank you

Comment: Ok you have to remove the margin-left..Check update!

Answer (score 1):

@Sylvester

I see that display table is used on the parent element and margin-left on one of the child elements. 
Personally I would have used something else, like display flex for example. 
But if you apply display table-cell and no width (on the default level/smallest viewport) on the child elements it will fix a lot :).

[image]